# How can I send a stream of data using Tokio's TcpStream?

Tags: tcp, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement a TCP client in Rust. I am able to read data coming from the server but I can not manage to send data.

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
extern crate bytes;
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use self::bytes::BytesMut;
use self::futures::{Future, Poll, Stream};
use self::tokio_core::net::TcpStream;
use self::tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use self::tokio_io::AsyncRead;
use std::io;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct TcpClient {}

struct AsWeGetIt<R>(R);

impl<R> Stream for AsWeGetIt<R>
where
    R: AsyncRead,
{
    type Item = BytesMut;
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        let mut buf = BytesMut::with_capacity(1000);

        self.0
            .read_buf(&mut buf)
            .map(|async| async.map(|_| Some(buf)))
    }
}

impl TcpClient {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }

    pub fn connectToTcpServer(&mut self) -> bool {
        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        let handle = core.handle();

        let address = "127.0.0.1:2323".parse().expect("Unable to parse address");
        let connection = TcpStream::connect(&address, &handle);

        let client = connection
            .and_then(|tcp_stream| {
                AsWeGetIt(tcp_stream).for_each(|buf| {
                    println!("{:?}", buf);
                    Ok(())
                })
            })
            .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Error: {}", e));

        core.run(client).expect("Unable to run the event loop");
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I add asynchronous data sending functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have two completely independent streams of data on the socket, you can use the [`split()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.8/tokio/prelude/trait.Stream.html#method.split) method on the `TcpStream` in the current version of Tokio:

```
let connection = TcpStream::connect(&address);
connection.and_then(|socket| {
    let (rx, tx) = socket.split();
    //Independently use tx/rx for sending/receiving
    return Ok(());
});
```

After the split, you can use `rx` (the receiving half) and `tx` (the sending half) independently. Here is a small example that treats sending and receiving as completely independent. The sender-half simply periodically sends the same message, whereas the receiving half just prints all incomming data:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

use self::futures::{Future, Poll, Stream};
use self::tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite, Error, ReadHalf};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Interval;

//Receiver struct that implements the future trait
//this exclusively handles incomming data and prints it to stdout
struct Receiver {
    rx: ReadHalf<TcpStream>, //receiving half of the socket stream
}
impl Future for Receiver {
    type Item = ();
    type Error = Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
        let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 1000]; //reserve 1000 bytes in the receive buffer
                                          //get all data that is available to us at the moment...
        while let Async::Ready(num_bytes_read) = self.rx.poll_read(&mut buffer)? {
            if num_bytes_read == 0 {
                return Ok(Async::Ready(()));
            } //socket closed
            print!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..num_bytes_read]));
        }
        return Ok(Async::NotReady);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let address = "127.0.0.1:2323".parse().expect("Unable to parse address");
    let connection = TcpStream::connect(&address);
    //wait for the connection to be established
    let client = connection
        .and_then(|socket| {
            //split the successfully connected socket in half (receive / send)
            let (rx, mut tx) = socket.split();

            //set up a simple sender, that periodically (1sec) sends the same message
            let sender = Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000))
                .for_each(move |_| {
                    //this lambda is invoked once per passed second
                    tx.poll_write(&vec![82, 117, 115, 116, 10]).map_err(|_| {
                        //shut down the timer if an error occured (e.g. socket was closed)
                        tokio::timer::Error::shutdown()
                    })?;
                    return Ok(());
                }).map_err(|e| println!("{}", e));
            //start the sender
            tokio::spawn(sender);

            //start the receiver
            let receiver = Receiver { rx };
            tokio::spawn(receiver.map_err(|e| println!("{}", e)));

            return Ok(());
        }).map_err(|e| println!("{}", e));

    tokio::run(client);
}
```

For some applications, this is enough. However, often you will have a defined protocol / format on the connection. HTTP connections, for example, always consist of requests and responses, each of which consists of a header and the body. Instead of directly working on the byte level, Tokio offers the traits `Encoder` and `Decoder` you fit onto a socket, which decodes your protocol and directly gives you the entities you want to work with. For an example you can either look at the very basic [HTTP implementation](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/46353737e7ce60ec8b3e77c044a6b2583de2fd51/examples/tinyhttp.rs#L111-L225) or the [line-based](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/3dd95a9ff14109f2b27d181960f478ad67c0c1ae/tokio-codec/src/lines_codec.rs) codec.

It gets a bit more complicated when an incoming message triggers an outgoing message. For the simplest case (every incoming message leads to exactly one outgoing message) you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/46353737e7ce60ec8b3e77c044a6b2583de2fd51/examples/tinydb.rs#L119-L155) official request / response example.